# How to override woocommerce customize panel file (in folder includes)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm overriding Woocommerce theme. And now I have to override customize panel. There is a few woocommerce default sections in Customize panel to change some Woocommerce data, labels etc. (such as image size, number of post per page, privacy text...). And I want to **add my own customize panel fields** to make some data in my child theme to be easy to change (they should be placed in the same control panel sections next to Woocommerce default fields).

There is `Woocommerce/Includes/Customizer/*customizer files*`. So I can simply override that files in Woocommerce folder but when Woocommerce will be updated I'll lose my changes.

So I need to **add my customize fields** (and I think the best way is write them somewhere in my child theme maybe in `functions.php` but I didn't manage to do it yet) in the same Woocommerce control panel tabs and sections. (For example in section **Product Catalog** (that's woocommerce default section) I want to make changeable my own filter label).
Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add your own section with settings under WooCommerce customize panel, just add follows codes snippets in your active theme's functions.php -

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_custom_customize_register', 99 );
function my_custom_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'my_wc_custom_section',
        array(
            'title'    => __( 'My Custom Section', 'text-domain' ),
            'priority' => 20,
            'panel'    => 'woocommerce',
            'description' => '', 
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_wc_custom_section_settings', array( 'transport' => 'postMessage' ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'my_wc_custom_section_settings_control', 
        array(
            'label'     => __( 'Custom Text', 'text-domain' ),
            'type'      => 'text',
            'settings'  => 'my_wc_custom_section_settings',
            'section'   => 'my_wc_custom_section',
            'priority'  => 20,
        ) 
    );
}
```

To display your saved field's value from your custom section settings, just use follows -

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'my_wc_custom_section_settings' );
```

Thats it.